# How to use weighted selection for infinite numbers?

Tags: python, random

I’m trying to make a luck game where you roll to get random numbers, but you have more chance to get a percentage closer to 100.

The weight distribution is the number itself. For example, it would be 4x less likely to roll a number around 25 than roll a number closer to 100.

I tried weighted selection, but there was a big problem: it could only work with numbers in the list.

I wondered if it was possible to make it work with any number.

Here’s the code (there’s a step of 0.01 between the numbers)

```
import random
import numpy as np

def pickNb(step, limit):
    lst = np.arange(step, limit, step)

    return 100 / limit * random.choices(lst, weights=lst)[0]

print(f"{pickNb(0.01, 1)}%")
```

As you can see, the program can’t return numbers smaller than 0.01.

After buying upgrades, the player would get numbers closer to 0.01, and never smaller numbers.

Also, if the step was too small, it would take exponentially longer to initialize the list.

Comment: @Corralien this site requires questions, answers, and comments to be in English - please stick to the rules. As I'm sure you're aware OP, the question is what number you're looking to obtain and what the problem is exactly.

Comment: There are continuous weighted distributions, but this is not answerable unless you say *in explicit mathematical terms* what the distribution you *want* is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for is the [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution), parameterized with a min of 0 and 100 for both the max and mode. This would give you a continuous distribution where the likelihood of outcomes grows linearly — the property you specified when you said it should "be 4x less likely to roll a number around 25 than roll a number closer to 100".

Continuous distributions are implemented algebraically or algorithmically, not with lists. This eliminates the issues you noted with initialization and unreachable ranges, both of which are artifacts of trying to discretize the problem. Since the results are floating point, there aren't an infinite set of possible outcomes but this is a much better approximation to continuous than discretizing in increments of 0.01.

Change the parameterization after the user buys upgrades to shift the range appropriately. Since you haven't provided any specifics on how things should be adjusted, neither can I.

You can get triangle distributions using [random.triangular](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#real-valued-distributions) or [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.triangular.html).